# Check if JSON is Structure or Array in Groovy Script

Tags: arrays, groovy

I have below payload and I have requirement to check whether scheduleElements is jsonArray or Not how can I achieve that ?

```
{
   "value":{
      "ID":"1c1238c8-3517-47c7-83de-6269fa6098cc",
      "parentSubProject_ID":"11593e45-6db1-48ee-98b4-422dba621adb",
      "scheduleElements":{
         "ID":"92a1352d-8319-4e1a-b921-0d7d0ee9f59e",
         "parentItem_ID":"1c1238c8-3517-47c7-83de-6269fa6098cc",
         "startDate":"2025-05-30",
         "endDate":"2025-05-30",
         "dateType":"none",
         "type":"SOP",
         "timelineElement_ID":"f08dc9df-89fb-4490-9117-40c2f094e4ba",
         "timelineElementType":"",
         "manuallyModifiedAt":"",
         "milestoneSortOrder":"0",
         "sortOrder":"0",
         "dateTypeSortOrder":"0"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse it, and check if it's a list

```
Boolean isList = new JsonSlurper()
    .parseText(json)
    .value
    .scheduleElements instanceof List
```

Comment: Does `ScheduleElements` need to be `scheduleElements`?

Comment: Gaaah! Thanks Jeff 